# Father's Obligations to Children

Tags: children-parenting, divorce

What are a father's obligations or responsibilities to his children?  Is there any guidance on what happens to those obligations or responsibilities after a divorce?  Is there any guidance on what a father should provide in terms of financial and emotional support?

Comment: A more specific question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9807

Comment: BLR, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! It seems to me that this question is intended to specifically address a father's responsibilities post-divorce. If so, I recommend that you [edit] both the title and body to focus specifically on that. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 3):

See gemarah [Kiddushin 29](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=29&format=pdf) which says a father is obligated to circumcise his son, redeem him (if he is a firstborn), teach him Torah, marry him off, teach him a trade, and (according to some) teach him how to swim. See [daf 30](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=30&format=pdf) for chinuch.

Comment: Is a father also obligated to teach his daughter to swim?